# AbstractMethodError with JavaAssist

Tags: java, interface

So, 
   I have JavaAssist implement interfaces and add the getters/setters that the interfaces provide. I then gain a new instance of one of the classes which now has an interface and try to call things from it:

```
interfaceWrapper.getMainInterface().getLowerInterface()
```

However, I get an AbstractMethodError on the `getLowerInterface()` call, but I have had JavaAssist inject that method into the class.

Any ideas on how to invoke this method? Am I doing something wrong interface-wise or JavaAssist-wise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `AbstractMethodError` [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html):

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

If this is an error occurring during compilation, you are perhaps doing something such as calling `super.getLowerInterface()` in a sub-class (of the class in which the abstract version is defined).

If this is happening during runtime, then a *.class file was changed and re-compiled, but another class requiring it was not re-compiled.

You should be take a close look at `interfaceWrapper.getMainInterface().getLowerInterface()`, by specifically tracing that call all the way through to its final destination, which obviously must be a non-existing--abstract--function.

Comment: I had JavaAssist dump the class for me, and it' showing the method implemented.. It's a runtime issue. Is there any easy way to find out which class is causing the issue?

Comment: If it's a runtime error, this implies that all your source code needs to be re-compiled. A compilation error should pop-up, and it should be pretty easy to understand.